# jquery traverse dom with dot notation

Tags: jquery, html

I have looked and looked to try and find an answer to this, but i cant find anything. or dont know the right words to look for.

essentially im working with this html:

```
<article>
<a href="link.com">
    <div class="item" id="1">
        <div class="description">
            <div class="number">#532567</div>
            <a href="1.html">see more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="link.com">
    <div class="item" id="2">
        <div class="description">
            <div class="number">#533581</div>
            <a href="2.html">see more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

essentially what i want to do is get all the pieces of this in a loop and then output my own json that is better arranged than the html code.

i have this jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('article > a').each(function(i,v) {
        //right now, 't', 'this', and 'v' are all THE SAME OBJECT
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var div = $(this).find('.item').html();
            var number = div.description.number.val();
        console.log('href['+href+'] div['+div+'] number['+number+']');
    });
});
```

and href outputs correctly but div is undefined, and i get a 'cant read propert of description of undefined' on number.

i want to use dot notation to achieve this. and i'd like to be able to tap into:
div.item id value
div.description div.number html
etc

any pointers appreciated.

Comment: There is no `.card` inside the `a` anchors in the HTML provided - perhaps you mean `.item`?

Comment: yes, sorry, card is supposed to be item

Comment: Can you show the exact output you want, given the HTML posted in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it seemed to work (selecting each `.item` instead)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.item').each(function (index, value) {
        //right now, 't', 'this', and 'v' are all THE SAME OBJECT
        var href = $(value).parent().find('a').attr('href');
        var divId = $(value).attr('id');
        var number = $(value).find('.number').html();
        console.log('href[' + href + '] div[' + divId + '] number[' + number + ']');
    });
});
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4sfq82qt/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('article > a').each(function(i,v) {
        //right now, 't', 'this', and 'v' are all THE SAME OBJECT
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var div = $(this).find('.item');
            var number = div.find('.description .number').html();
        console.log('href['+href+'] div['+div.html()+'] number['+number+']');
    });
});
```

Comment: im getting: href[link.com] div[undefined] number[undefined]

Comment: This probably not working because you have nested <a> tag in another <a> tag.

Comment: @RobertKarczmarczyk I stand corrected - I will remove my previous comment